# Find rank of the matrix $a_{ij}=(i-j)^2$, $i,j=1,\dots, n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let is $A$ $n\times n$ matrix defined in following way $a_{ij} = (i-j)^2$.
For example when $n=4$
$$
A= \begin{pmatrix}
0&1&4&9\\
1&0&1&4\\
4&1&0&1\\
9&4&1&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Find $\operatorname{rank}(A)$.

It seems we can make this matrix upper triangular and I suspect that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=n$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Denote the columns of $A$ by $C_1,C_2,\ldots ,C_n$. Since
$(j-i)^2=j^2-2ij+i^2$, we have $C_j=(j^2)V_1-2jV_2+V_3$ where
$V_1,V_2,V_3$ are the column vectors $(1,1,1,\ldots,1),(1,2,\ldots,n),
(1^2,2^2,\ldots,n^2)$. So the image of $A$ is contained in
the linear span of $V_1,V_2,V_3$ ; we deduce that the rank
of $A$ is at most $3$.

If $n\geq 3$, then $(C_1,C_2,C_3)$ are linearly independent, so
the rank of $A$ is exactly $3$.

To conclude, the rank of $A$ is $\min(3,n)$ (except for the trivial case of $n=1$ where $rank(A)=0$ ).

Comment: Except for the trivial case of $n=1$ where $\operatorname{rank}(A)=0$

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt corrected, thanks